# Default website in name-based apache virtual host configuration

Tags: apache, web, default, virtualhost

I am using name-based virtual host configuration, to serve different websites
from the same IP address. For example:

```
http://www.myserver.com/website1
http://www.myserver.com/website2
http://www.myserver.com/website3
...
http://www.myserver.com/websiten
```

All of them are stored into my server, in the directories:

```
/var/www/website1
/var/www/website2
/var/www/website3
...
/var/www/websiten
```

I want to use website1 as default website when browsing to URL:

```
http://www.myserver.com
```

To do that, I'm trying this method:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    ServerName www.myserver.com

    Alias / /var/www/website1       ### ALIAS HERE

    <Directory /var/www/website1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/website2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ...

    <Directory /var/www/websiten>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create hosts file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.myserver.com        
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/website1"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then create symlinks in your var/www/website1/ dir to point to the other dirs?

```
cd /var/www/website1/
ln -s /var/www/website2/ website2
ln -s /var/www/website3/ website3
```

if you have different domain names then you can configure vhost like so without symlinks, first instance uses the ServerAlias directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver.com
    ServerAlias www.myserver.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/website1"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName trac.myserver.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/website2"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed my issue. I have replaced

```
Alias / /var/www/website1       ### ALIAS HERE
```

by this Directory section:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /website1/
</Directory>
```

RedirectMatch fixes my issue. Now, when I browse this URL:

```
http://www.myserver.com
```

it is automatically converted to this:

```
http://www.myserver.com/website1/
```

I'm not sure if that is the best way to solve my issue, but at least, it works as expected. This can be marked as [Solved] yet.

Thank you in advance for help! :)